# Format Git/Build Time Information Using Spring Boot Actuator And git-commit-id-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-actuator

I'm using spring boot actuator and git-commit-id-maven-plugin to expose git/build information, however the time information is being displayed like this:

```
{
"git": {
    "commit": {
        "id": {
            "full": "67ad5677d4a8ad6f02adda28c3963bee17183c20"
        },
        "time": {
            "nano": 0,
            "epochSecond": 1627493496
        }
    },
...
```

Is there a way to format the time to a more human readable format?

I've tried a couple of things but none of those worked, this is what I've tried:

1. Adding a dateFormat to the git-commit-id-maven-plugin:

   ```
     <plugin>
       <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
       <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.0</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
           <goals>
             <goal>revision</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>initialize</phase>
         </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
         <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</dateFormat>
         <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
         <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${basedir}/src/main/resources/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
         <includeOnlyProperties>
           <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.time$</includeOnlyProperty>
           <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id$</includeOnlyProperty>
           <includeOnlyProperty>^git.branch$</includeOnlyProperty>
         </includeOnlyProperties>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```
2. Adding these spring jackson properties to the `application.properties` file:

   ```
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds=false
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false/true
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-durations-as-timestamps =false/true
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-date-timestamps-as-nanoseconds =false/true
   ```
3. Add Instant serializer:

   ```
       DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
           .appendInstant(0)
           .toFormatter();
       JavaTimeModule jtm = new JavaTimeModule();
       jtm.addSerializer(Instant.class, new JsonSerializer<Instant>() {
           @Override
           public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
               gen.writeString(dtf.format(value));
           }
       });

   mapper.registerModule(jtm);
   ```

Along with this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Additional information, this is my git.properties:

```
#Generated by Git-Commit-Id-Plugin
git.branch=bugfix/PLATV2-12640
git.commit.id=67ad5677d4a8ad6f02adda28c3963bee17183c20
git.commit.time=2021-07-28T12\:31\:36-0500
```

And I'm using this spring-boot version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: You're not including the Jackson Java 8 time dependency.

Comment: Sorry, which dependency is that? @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: Is this one? 
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Comment: Always [search the name](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310). It identifies the replacement.

Comment: What does your `git.properties` look like? Which version of Spring Boot / Actuator are you using?

Comment: Helllo @slauth I've just updated the question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty late already, but today i got the same problem, and here is the reason, why it happens: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10392

So a simple solution is to use any other format than `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. Then spring won't convert it.

For example:

```xml
<dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</dateFormat>
```

worked absolutely fine for me